# How to determine the programming language

Tags: sqlite, programming-languages

I'm trying to find out, which programming language is used in these functions - newVersion() and curVersion(). I've tried to search in Google, even on exact match like "newVersion()" OR "curVersion()", but it does not find.
As db is used sqlite db.
If short, it's proprietary app and I don't have access to source code of app, but I have to resolve the issue with pop-up error in Android app.
Have anyone some ideas about that?

```
CREATE TABLE "tblEvents" (
    --some fields before
    "version"   int NOT NULL DEFAULT (newVersion()),
    "isModified"    int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("version" > curVersion()) VIRTUAL,
);
```

The error occurs in one of these triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_i_tblEvents] 
    BEFORE INSERT ON [tblEvents] 
        WHEN isVersionEnabled() AND new.version<>newVersion() 
            BEGIN SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'DON''T TOUCH ROW VERSION!!!'); ENDл
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_u_tblEvents] 
    BEFORE UPDATE OF version,SyncStatus,[EventId],[EventTypeId],[Name],[Description],[DateStart],[DateEnd],[CreationDate],[EventStatus],[OrgStructureID],[Color],[Location],[Mode],[StaffGroupID],[PlannedDay],[Recurrence_ID] 
        ON [tblEvents] 
            WHEN isVersionEnabled() AND new.version<>newVersion() 
                BEGIN SELECT CASE WHEN new.version<>old.version THEN RAISE(FAIL, 'DON''T TOUCH ROW VERSION!!!') END; 
    update [tblEvents] set version=newVersion() where rowId=old.rowId; ENDБ
```

Comment: Maybe a [Application-Defined SQL Function](https://www.sqlite.org/appfunc.html)?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true and these functions really implemented by developer on Application-Defined SQL Functions  or, mayby, in these methods are overrided some standart sqlite-functions.